# Are the strings returned by AES_ENCRYPT unique?

Tags: mysql, security, encryption, aes

I need to encrypt a column in MySQL and I am using AES_ENCRYPT. I want to figure out a safe way to use this data column in a WHERE clause. My question is this -

1) Can I AES_ENCRYPT the WHERE clause argument with the same pass-phrase and use the generated encrypted string in the WHERE clause? Or do I have to run decryption on the whole column?

For example, will this be safe?

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE Enc_COL= AES_ENCRYPT('someColValue','same_passphrase');
```

or does it have to be

```
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE AES_ENCRYPT(Enc_COL,'same_passphrase')= 'someColValue';
```

I believe the second one will be much slower and so, I want to know if the first example is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `Enc_COL` = AES_ENCRYPT('text-to-encrypt', 'same_passphrase');
```

should be fine.  Just make sure there is an index for `Enc_Col` so you don't have to scan the entire table for results.  As long as you use the same input and key you will get the same output.

Just a side note, don't use the same key for more than one column (make sure to use some sort of IV or crytographic nonce that's unique to each column you encrypt).  If you encrypt all of the rows with the same key and your database is compromised, it makes it much more likely that someone can find the key.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Could you also possibly point us to a theoretical reference of why this is okay? That would be awesome.

Comment: Well [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) is a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) so given the same key and message, the output will always be the same.  The decryption circuit works in reverse and given a ciphertext and key, the decryption of the ciphertext and same key will always be the same.  Is that what you were wanting clarification on?  It is for these reasons why you should never use the same key to encrypt data more than once.  Doing so opens up the possibility for a chosen or known plaintext attack.